# How to find searchable PDFs

Tags: pdf, grep, search

I have a folder with many PDFs. Some are no doubt searchable. Can I search for and identify only those which are searchable?

Adobe gives an error message if a PDF is an image, asking if you want to convert it to searchable text. I do not know if that is generic or specific to Adobe. I suppose a more complete question would have been how do I set aside the file if an image is encountered? I will read up on man `pdfinfo` to see if I find anything in there to help.

Comment: How do you classify a `.pdf` as "searchable"? Does `man pdfinfo` help?  Why not  "search" them all, ignoring errors  (`2>/dev/null`)?

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: @Pablo - Your first suggestion worked just fine and I am grateful. I am sure your second on "some stats" is also brilliant and DO I EVER want those. But when I execute your code nothing happens. Not sure what "Pipe to" means in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a particular folder you can use [pdfgrep](https://pdfgrep.or):

```
pdfgrep --recursive --count .
```

The lines with zero at the end are not searchable (the dot is a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that matches to any character). Also,

```sh
pdfgrep -r -c . | grep -oP "\:\d*$" | sed 's/^\:0$/Not searchable/g;s/^\:[1-9][0-9]*$/Searchable/' | sort | uniq -c
```

will give you some stats about how many are searchable or not.